# continuity on the common edge of the two tensor-product Bezier surfaces

Tags: tensor-products

The two tensor-product Bezier surfaces,with control points cij and dij
[image]
[image]

What are the conditions on the
control points that ensure that p and q join with c^1 continuity on the
common edge s = 1, 0 ≤ t ≤ 1?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the partial derivatives of $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ with respect to $s$ at parameter values $(1,t)$. You will find that they are both simple functions of the control points. Set the partial derivative expressions equal to each other, and use this equation to derive a relationship between control points.

Comment: Can you help me with the partial derivatives of p and q. I don't know how can I get derivative of tensor-product.